# How to get degrees by Accelerometer data (Java libGDX)

Tags: java, android, libgdx, accelerometer, smartphone

how can I get degrees from the values of the Accelerometer ? I'm useing libGDX and code in Java with Android Studio. 
I ve got a sprite animation, which walks straight. The point of View is orthogonal from top, and I want to rotate the sprite when I tilt the smartphone.

How can I get the 360° degrees on the screen, for example like a compass just instead that it points to north it should point to the direction where the smartphone is tilted. How is it possible with the Accelerometer Sensor ? Or what other possibility do I have ?

Sorry for my English

Comment: It should be possible to get the rotation matrix of the accelerometer and convert it to euler angles if you just want to have the angle numbers in degrees. I've done this once but I forgot where that code of mine is now.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Great! Please accept my answer, thanks. Good luck @Domooo93

Comment: How do i accept an an answer ? I didnt used this forum very often

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of doing this is to use a SensorManager and implement SensorEventListener. The basic idea is you use the SensorManager to register the Orientation sensor and then respond to changes in the orientation of the device in the onSensorChanged delegate method implemented with SensorEventListener. Make sure you unregister the listener onPause() or else it will kill your battery.

As a high level example:

```
public class SensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

private Sensor mOrientationSensor;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mOrientationSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mSensorManager != null) {
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mOrientationSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mOrientationSensor);
}


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float degree = Math.round(event.values[0]);

        // do something here
}
```

note: The orientation sensor has been deprecated, although I still think it works best. The updated approach is below if you'd like to try that.

From the android documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html#sensors-pos-orient

```
    public class SensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

  private SensorManager mSensorManager;
  private final float[] mAccelerometerReading = new float[3];
  private final float[] mMagnetometerReading = new float[3];

  private final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[9];
  private final float[] mOrientationAngles = new float[3];

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // Do something here if sensor accuracy changes.
    // You must implement this callback in your code.
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Get updates from the accelerometer and magnetometer at a constant rate.
    // To make batch operations more efficient and reduce power consumption,
    // provide support for delaying updates to the application.
    //
    // In this example, the sensor reporting delay is small enough such that
    // the application receives an update before the system checks the sensor
    // readings again.
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER,
      SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD,
      SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Don't receive any more updates from either sensor.
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
  }

  // Get readings from accelerometer and magnetometer. To simplify calculations,
  // consider storing these readings as unit vectors.
  @Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
      System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mAccelerometerReading,
        0, mAccelerometerReading.length);
    }
    else if (event.sensor == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
      System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mMagnetometerReading,
        0, mMagnetometerReading.length);
    }
  }

  // Compute the three orientation angles based on the most recent readings from
  // the device's accelerometer and magnetometer.
  public void updateOrientationAngles() {
    // Update rotation matrix, which is needed to update orientation angles.
    mSensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mRotationMatrix, null,
      mAccelerometerReading, mMagnetometerReading);

    // "mRotationMatrix" now has up-to-date information.

    mSensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, mOrientationAngles);

    // "mOrientationAngles" now has up-to-date information.
  }
}
```